# How to use the empty space left and right of a post?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, sidebar

(WordPress 3.5.1, theme 20-11)

I would like to use the red colored areas left and right to a post and can't find information on what plugin might deal with that.

How can I add content there - widgets f.x. Or would I have to change the theme? I would prefer to not alter the code for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: It appears that this question boils down to: *how do I change the code of this Theme, without changing the code*? As-asked, the question is un-answerable.

Comment: well - "there is no setting and no plugin for that purpose - and there is also no theme similar to 20-11 dealing with that." - would be a totally fine answer. you're welcome to make this clear statement - if you know it is true.

Comment: Twenty Eleven doesn't implement sidebars in the single blog post page template. Thus, to add them, you'll have to modify the code, to call `dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar )`, and you'll probably have to modify the markup and CSS to accommodate this new content. Thus, what you're asking can't be done in Twenty Eleven without modifying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get a sidebar next to pages and single-post pages:

1. Install "[Twenty Eleven Theme Extensions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twenty-eleven-theme-extensions/)"
2. Go to Appearance > Theme Extensions
3. Select "Enable the widget sidebar on (single-post) pages"

Done.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sidebars `Main` and `Showcase` in the theme. To make it showing on a page, go to this page and select appropriate page template in the page attributes meta box. Then sidebars will appear on your page.

[image]

Comment: I have a lot of widgets in my sidebar. But the sidebar is only added in the home/front page.

Comment: @Яaffael1984 I have updated my answer

Comment: that already helps a lot, thanks (+1) - but it does not apply to my question regarding posts.

Comment: @Яaffael1984 I don't understand what you asking there :) what do you want to do with posts? Go to theme options page, there is default layout settings, maybe it will help.

Comment: I want to use the empty white space next to posts - I don't see what's not clear about that :)

Comment: Use it for what? Use it how? @EugeneManuilov explained how you can use it for widgets. Wasn't that want you wanted?

Comment: @t f: the answer refers to and works with pages. it does not refer to and work with posts. pages and posts are handled differently in wordpress - they just look very similar.

Comment: There are no sidebars called in [the single blog post page template](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyeleven/1.5/single.php) in Twenty Eleven